# Jquery .show hides again after postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html-lists

I have an UL that I control using hide and show. The problem is that when I click on level1 it shows level2 for only a moment before it disappears, I believe this is because of a postback or something. The functionality works but it just doesnt stay like it. I need to be able to toggle the items in the list to show and hide them.

```
     <script>
      $(function(){
          $('.level2').hide();
          $('.level3').hide();
          $('.level1').click(function () {
              $('.level2').show();
                return false;
              $('level2').click(function () {
                  $('.level3').show();
                    return false;
                  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
              });
          })
      }
)
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function openNewWin(url) {

                var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,status=no');

                x.focus();

            }



    </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"/>

  <script>
      $(function(){
          $('.level2').hide();
          $('.level3').hide();
          $('.level1').click(function () {
              $('.level2').show();
                return false;
              $('level2').click(function () {
                  $('.level3').show();
                    return false;
                  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
              });
          })
      }
)
  </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="menu" class="MenuBar">
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="mainmenu" StaticDisplayLevels="3" Target="_blank" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" StaticSubMenuIndent="0px" >
      <LevelMenuItemStyles>
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level1"/>
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level2"/>
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level3" />
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level4" />

  </LevelMenuItemStyles>

    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="staticItem" />
        </asp:Menu>

</div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share the html as well

Comment: Are these anchors with href attributes ?

Comment: don't add a event listener inside another one also you have `return` statements before the `level2` click handler is added

Comment: I have added the HTML

Comment: No, you added the ASP.Net controls. Add the HTML, we have no idea what the result is of those controls.

Comment: It won't allow me to insert of all the generated HTML but it just generates an unordered list with 3 different classes depending on the levels, it works ok but the levels hide straight after they have been shown (on click).

Comment: Asp.Net menu generates it's own set of javascript functions to show/hide the levels on mouse hover. This is not what you want? You want to change the default behavior how?

Comment: I didnt change the default behaviour, you can change it in the properties. Just think of it Like a UL, I have the same issue if I use a normal UL so I know it's not an issue with the asp control and as I said it does work it just returns back to normal straight after